# SQL Running total by specific part

Tags: sql, join, window-functions

Looking for a running total type calculation based on a specific item order qty detail level.  I have an existing inventory by item (at time of report generation).

```
    create table SALES (
    ID INT,
    PART VARCHAR(12),
    QTY INT)

    CREATE TABLE INVENTORY (
    ID INT,
    PART VARCHAR (12),
    QTY INT)

INSERT INTO SALES (ID, PART, QTY)
VALUES (1, 1260, 10), 
(2, 1260, 10),
(3, 1153, 5),
(4, 1260, 5),
(5, 279, 20)

INSERT INTO INVENTORY (ID, PART, QTY)
VALUES (1000, 1260, 20),
(1010, 1153, 0),
(1100, 279, 100)
```

With above data loaded I get these results:

```
  SELECT A.ID AS 'ORDER ID', A.PART, A.QTY AS 'SALES QTY' , B.QTY AS 'INVENTORY'
    FROM SALES A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INVENTORY B ON A.PART = B.PART
    ORDER BY 2

ORDER ID    PART    SALES QTY   INVENTORY
3           1153    5           0
4           1260    5           20
1           1260    10          20
2           1260    10          20
5           279     20          100
```

I am looking for a running total by part at each order line level like below (Projected):

```
ORDER ID    PART    SALES QTY   INVENTORY   PROJECTED
3           1153    5           0           -5
4           1260    5           20          15
1           1260    10          20          5
2           1260    10          20          -5
5           279     20          100         80
```

I am a new poster to the site, have used many times in past from other users questions.....if I have posted something in a wrong format, I apologize.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions. However you do need an ordering column, and it is not obvious which one you would use here. I represented it with a question mark (`?`):

```
select 
    s.id order_id, 
    s.part, 
    s.qty sales_qty, 
    i.qty inventory,
    i.qty - sum(s.qty) over(partition by s.part order by ?) projected
from sales s
left outer join inventory i on i.part = s.part
order by 2
```

Comment: Obviously there is a lot more data, what exactly does the "order by" perform?

Comment: @shanegair: it defines in which order the sales quantity are counted for a given part. For example for part `1260`, you are processing sales id `4`, then `1`, then `2`. You need a column that can be used to define the ordering (obviously that's not `sales(id)`).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a window function and arithmetic:

```
SELECT S.ID AS ORDERID, S.PART, S.QTY AS SALESQTY , I.QTY AS INVENTORY,
       SUM(I.QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY S.PART ORDER BY S.ID) - S.QTY
FROM SALES S LEFT JOIN
     INVENTORY I
     ON I.PART = S.PART
ORDER BY 2
```